# How do I insert an element to a set that is a value in multimap C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, set, emplace

I have a trouble with adding a new values to a `set<Value_Class>` that is in my `map<Key, set<Values_Class>>`. When I try to add a value like this:

```cpp
Key key(get<0>(key_args), get<1>(key_args));
        if (!(get<0>(key_args) < 1 && get<0>(key_args) > m_existing_keys_set.size()) && m_existing_keys_set.find(key) != m_existing_keys_set.end())
        {
            Value_Class value(get<0>(value_args), get<1>(value_args), get<2>(value_args));
            set<Value_Class> _temp_set{ value };
            m_map_with_elements.emplace(move(key), move(_temp_set));
        }
```

There's only the first value I added in the map. The other values just don't insert, there's always only the first added value. Can You help me and tell how should I solve a problem? The whole code:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple> 
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Main_Class
{
private:  //private section for classes and some helper functions
    class Value_Class; struct Key;

    set<Key> m_existing_keys_set
    {
        {1, "Key"}
    }; // all the existing keys will be stored here

    /*----------------------classes start space------------------*/
    /// 
    ///  Value_Class
    /// 
    class Value_Class
    {
    public:

        
    private:
        string m_value_name;
        fouble m_value_double_data;
        bool m_is_available;

    public:
        Value_Class(string val_name, double val_double_data, bool is_avialable) : //Values_Class Constructor
            m_value_name(move(val_name)),
            m_value_double_data(val_double_data),
            m_is_available(is_avialable) {};

        ~Value_Class() {};


        
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Value_Class& dish) {//    Overloading the output << operator
            return os << dish.m_value_name << " >-=-=-=-< Price: " << dish.m_value_double_data;
        }

        bool operator<(const Value_Class& dish) const {//   Overloading the < operator
            return tie(m_value_name, m_value_double_data, m_is_available) < tie(dish.m_value_name, dish.m_value_double_data, dish.m_is_available);
        }

    };

    /// 
    ///  KEY
    /// 
    struct Key
    {
        typedef int dish_number_category_t;
        typedef string dish_name_category_t;
    private:
        dish_number_category_t m_key_number;
        dish_name_category_t m_key_name;
    public:
        Key(dish_number_category_t num, dish_name_category_t str) : // Key constructor
            m_key_number(num),
            m_key_name(move(str)) {};

        bool operator<(const Key& rhs) const {
            return tie(m_key_number, m_key_name) < tie(rhs.m_key_number, rhs.m_key_name);

        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Key& k) {
            return os << k.m_key_name;
        }
        bool operator==(const Key& _key) const
        {
            return tie(_key.m_key_number, _key.m_key_name) == tie(m_key_number, m_key_name);
        }
    };

    /*----------------------classes end space------------------*/

    template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
    void add_helper(tuple<Args1...> key_args,
        tuple<Args2...> value_args) // Helper method
    {
        Key key(get<0>(key_args), get<1>(key_args));
        if (!(get<0>(key_args) < 1 && get<0>(key_args) > m_existing_keys_set.size()) && m_existing_keys_set.find(key) != m_existing_keys_set.end())
        {
            Value_Class value(get<0>(value_args), get<1>(value_args), get<2>(value_args));
            set<Value_Class> _temp_set{ value };
            m_map_with_elements.emplace(move(key), move(_temp_set));
        }
    }


public: static Main_Class* get_instance();

private: // private section for all singleton stuff
    Main_Class() {};
    Main_Class(const Main_Class&) = delete;
    Main_Class operator=(const Main_Class&) = delete;

    static Main_Class* _instance; // The only object og the Maim_Class
    map<Key, set<Value_Class>> m_map_with_elements; // the map 

public: // public section for all the public functions
    template <class... Args>
    void add_new_element_to_a_map(Args&&... args)
    {
        add_helper(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    void print_map() const
    {
        for (auto& itr : m_map_with_elements)
        {
            cout << "Key: " << itr.first << endl;
            for (auto& itr2 : itr.second)
                cout << itr2 << endl;
        }
    }
};
Main_Class* Main_Class::_instance = 0;


Main_Class* Main_Class::get_instance()

{
    if (_instance == 0)
        _instance = new Main_Class();

    return _instance;

} //Singleton access function
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Is there something wrong with [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)?

Comment: Tried to use it, but I found that using map of unique keys and sets as values is better 
(not sure about that at all now tbh)

Comment: One difference is with a std::multimap, you can have a key-value pair in it multiple times, but with a key-set in the (value) set you can only have one unique value.  Maybe that works better for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You've assumed that `std::map::emplace()` will effectively take care of the key duplication while the documentation said that it's not guaranteed.

> The element may be constructed even if there already is an element
> with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed
> element will be destroyed immediately.

check out [std::map::emplace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace)

You can use `std::map::erase()` to erase the item if it exists, then you will get the expected behavior.

```
template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
void add_helper(tuple<Args1...> key_args,
    tuple<Args2...> value_args) // Helper method
{
    Key key(get<0>(key_args), get<1>(key_args));
    if (!(get<0>(key_args) < 1 && get<0>(key_args) > m_existing_keys_set.size()) && m_existing_keys_set.find(key) != m_existing_keys_set.end())
    {
        Value_Class value(get<0>(value_args), get<1>(value_args), get<2>(value_args));
        set<Value_Class> _temp_set{ value };
        m_map_with_elements.erase(key);
        m_map_with_elements.emplace(move(key), move(_temp_set));
    }
}
```

You can also provide your own hand-crafted function to handle this.